# How to add a colormap to a barplot (such as Viridis), varying color vertically?

Tags: python, bar-chart, colormap

I want to to reproduce the BarPlots shown in this article:

https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acsnano.8b04726

I have already plotted the graph, but I can't get to color the bars with the Viridis Colormap like the authors did, where the greater the value the more yellow the bar becomes at the top.

How can I use such a colormap to color the bars in Python?

Thanks!

Here is the code I'm using at Jupyter Notebook to plot the Bar Chart.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from cycler import cycler
import matplotlib as mpl
import pandas as pd

#Imports data for the y-axis bars
df = pd.read_excel('Mydata')
heightof = df['pce']
pce_std = [0.05, 0.11, 0, 0, 0.13, 0.32, 0.00007, 0.17, 0.05, 0.28, 0.08, 0.35, 0.04, 0.12, 0.10]
axis_x = range(1,16)

#Plots Bar Chart
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1, 1, clear=True, figsize=(8,6))
plt.bar(axis_x, heightof, width=0.9, bottom=0, align='center', yerr=pce_std)
plt.ylabel('PCE / %', fontsize=15)
plt.xlabel('N of Experiments', fontsize=15)
plt.title(r"$\bf{a}$"+'    Run: 1', fontsize=20)
plt.xticks(np.arange(1, 16, step=2), ('1-1', '1-3', '1-5', '1-7','1-9', '1-11', '1-13', '1-15'))
ax1.xaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=12)
ax1.yaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=12)

plt.show()
```

However, my bars are all blue, and I want them to be colored like the ones shown in the article.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please show the code of what you already achieved. In particular this question might need a little more context of what tools you are trying to use.